# How to use label symbol in absolute expressions in gnu assembler

Tags: assembly, gnu

As an example, say I want to restrict the length of a block of code.

```
begin:
nop;nop;nop;nop
end:
.if end-begin>20
.err
.endif
```

The compiler prints "Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement".

A related question. Is there a way to print calculated expression while compiling? `.print` only accepts a character string.

Comment: My `gas` version 2.22 accepts that code as is. What version are you using?

Comment: Note that an assembler doesn't *compile* your code, it *assembles* your code.  Please be careful to make this distinction or your questions might be really hard to understand.